# Connect PHP to a local SQL 2008 Express database?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have spent about a day troubleshooting this and I can't find anything wrong. I get the error:

```
Could not connect to server: SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]
[message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
```

when I try to hit a page that has a db query. I have tried PHP 5.4 and 5.3. My .ini file has the lines,

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll

[sqlsrv]
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems = 0
sqlsrv.LogSeverity = 0
sqlsrv.WarningReturnAsErrors = 0
```

and php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll is in the ext folder. `phpinfo()` shows:

```
sqlsrv
sqlsrv support  enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize    10240   10240
sqlsrv.LogSeverity  0   0
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems    0   0
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors   On  On
```

so I know the driver is loaded. My connection code is:

```
define('DB_SERVER',     '(local)\sqlexpress');
define('DB_NAME',       'DatabaseName');

public function __construct() {
    $connectionInfo = array('Database' => DB_NAME, 'ReturnDatesAsStrings' => true);
    $this->connection = sqlsrv_connect( DB_SERVER, $connectionInfo ) or die('Could not connect to server: <br/><br/>'.print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

This is a local db, so there shouldn't be any issues with tcp, named pipes, etc. I can connect to this db fine in .Net projects. At this point I'm open to anything as I've scoured Google and Stack Overflow and tried just about everything.

Comment: Have you tried changing `(local)` to the actual machine name?

Comment: Yep, I tried that and I turned on tcp, opened the sql port, tried the machine's IP address too.